# How to build product flavors from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have defined some product flavors in my build.gradle. I am able to successfully build them using `gradlew`.

I can't figure out how I do so from the Android Studio IDE.

(My project was initially done in Eclipse then I've migrated to the Android Studio)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Build Variants appears as a vertical button along the bottom of the left edge of the workspace. If it's not visible, click the little rectangle icon on the lower left corner.

Comment: This window is empty though

Comment: In that case, the IDE is out of sync with your gradle config. If you've tried the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" with no success, I'm afraid I don't know what to do short of deleting all idea files and re-importing.

Comment: You're welcome. Hopefully the sync button goes away in the future as they update Android Studio. For now it seems to be the "fix this error I don't quite understand" button.

Comment: jsesus that is a dumb placement

Answer (score 32):

You can Choose the flavor you want to run on device or emulator selecting from the BuildVariants panel

[image]

To generate all the apk of each flavor , you can run the Gradle build task and the files will appear in the folder yourmodule / build / ouputs / apk .

Build task can be run from the console or from the task pane Gradle

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the upper right hand corner of android studio click "gradle".

Drop down your package > tasks > build > build { DOUBLE CLICK IT }

This will begin building all your flavors.

[[image]

[[image]