# How to use flavors in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

In my application i want use flavors into my application.
I added below codes into `build.gradle` file but when run application on device (click on run button from AndroidStudio) show me wrong data!
**My flavors codes:**

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.app"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 13
    versionName "1.0.13"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
    //Custom flavors
    flavorDimensions "default"
    productFlavors {
        appFlav2 {
            applicationId "com.app.app.myapp2"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "App name 2"
            resValue "string", "appDescription", "description info 2"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@drawable/logo_niaz"
            ]
        }
        appFlav3 {
            applicationId "com.app.app.myapp3"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "App name 3"
            resValue "string", "appDescription", "description info 3"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@drawable/logo_niaz"
            ]
        }
        appFlav {
            applicationId "com.app.app"
            resValue "string", "app_name", "App name"
            resValue "string", "appDescription", "description info"
            manifestPlaceholders = [
                    appIcon: "@drawable/launcher"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

But when running application on device show info of this flavor : **appFlav3** . but my default flavor is **appFlav** !

How can i fix it?

Comment: Change product flavor from Android Studio side menu. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234499/how-to-build-product-flavors-from-android-studio)

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman, thanks my friend for your help. it's work me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to select build variant to run the respective flavor. To find the build variants tab take a look at below screenshot.

[image]